# JavaScript, jQuery, AJAX and accented characters: how to get them working?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I'm experiencing a problem with the display of accented characters via AJAX and jQuery. I'll explain it in more detail.

I have a page where it has an `input` field. When I fill that field with 4 characters (which must be an ICAO code for an airport), it calls a PHP script via AJAX. The script is the following:

**File:** *ajax.airport.php*

```
<?php
    include("mysqlexec.inc.php");
    include("functions.inc.php");

    if(isset($_GET['icao'])){ 
        $airportData = GetAirportInfo($_GET['icao']);  

        if (!empty($airportData["Name"])) {
            echo $airportData["Name"];
        } else {
            echo "Not found!";
        }
    }
?>
```

The function `GetAirportInfo();` makes a HTTP request to the [Our Airports](http://www.ourairports.com/) website, where the airport's name is displayed. If you can check [this example page](http://www.ourairports.com/airports/SBGL/pilot-info.html), you may note that the ICAO code is ***SBGL***, which was entered by the user on the `input` and the return of the `GetAirportInfo();` function (which is the element of an array) will be ***Galeão - Antônio Carlos Jobim Intl***, with some accented characters.

The problem is, when echoing this on the file, there appears **Gale�o - Ant�nio Carlos Jobim Intl** instead.

All files are `UTF-8` (without BOM). I tried several functions (PHP and JS types), but that proved to be unsuccessful.

The jQuery function executed on the input is this:

```
function showAirport(icao, dest) {
    var icao=icao.toUpperCase();

    if (icao.length < 4) {
       $("#"+dest).html("");
    } else {
       $("#"+dest).html('<img src="images/loadingsm.gif"/>');
       $.ajax({
           type    : "GET",
           url     : "ajax.airport.php",
           dataType: "html",
           data    : { icao: icao },
           success : function (result) {
               $("#"+dest).html(result);
           },
       });
    }
};
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: how about database ? are records encoding correct ? by the way, at example page, encoding seems correct to me (mac os, chrome)

Comment: Actually those data are not being recorded on any database. The intention is to be displayed only for the user crosscheck and realizing that he entered the right ICAO code. - Example page is not mine, it's from Our Airports site, from where I take the information. Our Airports is not maintained by me: it's just from where I extract the data, with their permission.

Comment: did you tried [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding) ? or you can try like


    echo utf8_encode($airportData["Name"]);

Comment: are you printing these on an html page? if yes, check that you have a meta tag with charset="utf-8" specified. I'd also try charset="iso-8859-15", if utf-8 doesn't work for you.

Comment: My `meta` tag is `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`. I'm studying the `mb_detect_encoding` function.

Comment: @tanaydin, the usage of `utf8_decode` did the trick! I had a wrong understanding of the function, but you quote made me review it correctly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

have check contentType attribute

```
function showAirport(icao, dest) {
var icao=icao.toUpperCase();

if (icao.length < 4) {
   $("#"+dest).html("");
} else {
   $("#"+dest).html('<img src="images/loadingsm.gif"/>');
   $.ajax({
       type    : "GET",
       contentType: "text/xml;charset=utf-8",
       url     : "ajax.airport.php",
       dataType: "html",
       data    : { icao: icao },
       success : function (result) {
           $("#"+dest).html(result);
       },
   });
}
```

};

Comment: That charset on `contentType` is already the default [according to the jQuery's API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should encode `$airportData["Name"]` before it echoes in ajax.airport.php, use `json_encode()` before the data echo by ajax. Some other language need encode that the browser can  identify

```
include("mysqlexec.inc.php");
include("functions.inc.php");

if(isset($_GET['icao'])){ 
    $airportData = GetAirportInfo($_GET['icao']);  

    if (!empty($airportData["Name"])) {
        echo json_encode($airportData["Name"]);
    } else {
        echo "Not found!";
    }
}
```